# (flutter web) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'auth')

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions

I have a flutter web project and I use firebase services, The project was working perfectly until I add the package **"cloud_functions 3.3.7"**, a problem appaired in **firebase auth**.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'auth')

I tried to remove the package **"cloud_functions 3.3.7"** and the problem is still the same.

I tried to add these packages in index.html.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
```

it shows this error

> FirebaseError: Firebase: firebase.auth() takes either no argument or a Firebase App
> instance. (app/invalid-app-argument).

code to init Firebase

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```

```
dependencies:
  firebase_core: ^1.13.1
  firebase_analytics: ^9.1.2
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.10
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.10
  cloud_functions: ^3.3.7 
  firebase_storage: ^10.2.9
```

Comment: Hi, you need to share all the code used to initialize Firebase and desired services. At the moment, with the info shared in your answer, it’s difficult to analyse your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I create a new project flutter and I replace the files(lib, assets,..) and add packages in **pubspec.yaml** and it works perfectly and link it with firebase.

```
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
flutterfire configure --project=your_project_id
```

it's not a perfect solution but it still works.